# Update value in session array php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have question about the SESSION array.

I just add item and qty in different session. I use code like this :

```
$_SESSION['idproduct'] = $id.",";
$_SESSION['qtyproduct'] = $qty.",";
```

I have write the condition so the value of session will be like this if we add 3 item :

```
$_session['idproduct'] = 1,4,6,
$_session['qtyproduct'] = 3,4,5,
```

my question is how to update quantity if i have get the id ?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't use arrays to store your data? It would be easier (product id as key and quantity as value).

Comment: When you say `how to update quantity if i have get the id ?` do you mean that you want to update the quantity but you no longer know the productid?

Comment: @PiTiNiNja i don't know how to use key and value for array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean I know the id of product but i dont know how to update quantity in session

Comment: @user3551629 - The Styphon's answer will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them as arrays, that way you can access the quantity using the ID as a key:

```
$_SESSION['quantity'][$id] = $quantity;
```

So instead of storing your ID and Quantity in two separate strings, you have them in one array, with the ID as the key. Converting your example above your array will look like this:

```
array(
    1    => 3
    4    => 4
    6    => 5
);
```

Then if you wanted to add / adjust anything you just set `$id` and `$quantity` to the appropriate values and use the line above.

Comment: This is what (I think) the OP should do. WAY more simple than to use concatenation of variables...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode` function and push another item into the `array`

```
$items = explode($_SESSION['idproduct']);
$items[] = $your_new_value;
print_r($items); // this will you the values inside the array.
$_SESSION['idproduct'] = implode(',', $items);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve it is to store quantity as a value with product ID as a key, so if you have:

```
idproduct  = 1,4,6,
qtyproduct = 3,4,5,
```

Store it as:

```
$_SESSION['qtyproduct'] = array(
  1 => 3,
  4 => 4,
  6 => 5,
);
```

Right now if you have a product id:

```
$id = 4;
```

You can access quantity with:

```
$quantity = $_SESSION['qtyproduct'][$id];
```

and modify it with:

```
$_SESSION['qtyproduct'][$id] = 7;
```